# Convert 3D points to 2D points in another coordinate system using a table of correspondance with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, geometry

I have several pairs of images + cloud of 3D points that correspond to the same view. There are no rules for the change of coordinates. Everything is stored in a table.

- Rows : image x coordinate
- Columns : image y coordinate
- Cell: 3D points (x,y,z) coordinates.

Practically, this is a NumPy array of dimensions (1920, 1080, 3).

The other way around, finding the coordinate of the 3D point when you have the coordinate in the image is pretty straightforward.

```py
def image_to_xyz(self,image_points):
    """
    Takes a point in the image
    Return corresponding xyz coordinates
    """
    xyz = self.xyz
    image_points_x = image_points[:,0]
    image_points_y = image_points[:,1]
    xyz_points = xyz[image_points_x,image_points_y]
    return xyz_points
```

For the other way around, it is easy, but dirty, to make a for loop and search for a corresponding point with a precision threshold. I tried it.

It's in python, I can't use Julia, so the loop took several minutes to complete. Way too much...

Do you have better suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: There might be a bit better way, but here's an idea. If the xyz points are unique, you can sort them in ascending order and keep their respective original indices. Then you can search for a certain point using the bisect algorithm and fetch its index.

Comment: What is the type of the 3D points: Integers or floats? If they are floats, are the values ensured to be *exactly* the same between the one in `xyz_points` and the ones fetched? (see: [float format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format))

Comment: Float32, I tried to make a lookup loop that try to find near coordinates with a precision of 10-5. It works but it is extremely slow. So now my strategy is to rewrite the original program to always have the image xy paired with the 3D xyz.